# Как эффективней вычислить определитель матрицы?

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация, матрицы, линейная-алгебра

Код ниже считает определитель матрицы 20х20 методом миноров и записывает время, которое ему понадобилось для расчета. Но такую большую матрицу он считает очень долго, несколько часов...

```py
import time, random
from random import randint

Ic = [0 for i in range(10)]

def minor(array):
    return array[0][0] * array[1][1] - array[1][0] * array[0][1]

def division(array):
    if len(array[0]) > 2:
        result = 0
        for i in range(len(array[0])):
            new_arr = []
            for j in range(len(array[0])):
                if j != i:
                    new_arr.append([array[j][k] for k in range(1, len(array[0]))])
            result += division(new_arr) * array[i][0] * (-1 + 2 * ((i + 1) % 2))
        return result
    else:
        return minor(array)

N = 20
result = 0
print(f"\nN:\t{N}\n")
timer = time.time()
matrix = [[randint(0, 9) for row in range(N)] for row in range(N)]
print(f"result:\t{division(matrix)}")
for i in range(N):
    print(matrix[i])
print(f"Time:\t{time.time() - timer}")
```

Как это можно оптимизировать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Как это можно оптимизировать?

воспользоваться модулем `numpy`:

```
In [32]: import numpy as np   #  pip install numpy

In [33]: a = np.random.rand(20, 20)

In [34]: res = np.linalg.det(a)

In [35]: res
Out[35]: 0.09252260373277807
```

время работы для матрицы 20x20:

```
In [36]: %timeit np.linalg.det(a)
27.6 µs ± 37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: ну вы прямо серпом по яйцам, взяли и применили готовое решение :( а где элемент творчества?!!! :)

Comment: @Zhihar, дайте пожалуйста знать если в результате применения "элемента творчества" вы найдете решение, которое работает быстрее ;)

Comment: попробовал - приведение определителя к треугольному виду для 20 даёт где-то время 0.0029 :)

Comment: @Zhihar, сравните свое решение с `%timeit np.linalg.det(a)` на своем железе ;)

Comment: @MaxU, я вас, наверное, где-то не понял, но 36 строка вызывает invalid syntax

Comment: @Listopad02, это надо запускать либо в `iPython` (Intercative Python) либо в `Jupyter Notebook` - `%timeit np.linalg.det(a)`

Comment: MaxU, я правда вставил в код измерения времени автора  - мой `res: 1.2691632169503762e+59 Time: 0.0009772777557373047`, ваш `res: 1.2691632169505266e+59 Time: 0.0009784698486328125`, т.е. там как раз используется приведение определителя к треугольному виду - кстати дрянь еще та, поскольку из-за делений очень может поехать точность :)

Answer (score 4):

Вычисление определителя через миноры имеет факториальную сложность и непригодно для n>10.

Вместо этого стоит реализовать [LU разложение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) матрицы (кубическая сложность) и затем вычислить определитель как произведение диагональных элементов L и U матриц.